# r data.table - exclude groups that contain certain values in rows

Tags: r, data.table

This is an example data table:

```
set.seed(100)

> A <- data.table( a = sample(c('x','c','y',''),10, replace = T), b = sample(as.Date(c('2008-12-31','2012-12-31','2013-12-31','2014-12-31','2016-12-31')),10, replace = T) , c = runif(10)  )

> A
    a          b         c
 1: c 2014-12-31 0.5358112
 2: c 2016-12-31 0.7108038
 3: y 2012-12-31 0.5383487
 4: x 2012-12-31 0.7489722
 5: c 2014-12-31 0.4201015
 6: c 2014-12-31 0.1714202
 7:   2012-12-31 0.7703016
 8: c 2012-12-31 0.8819536
 9: y 2012-12-31 0.5490967
10: x 2014-12-31 0.2777238
```

Column a contains either x, y, c, or empty. I would like to group by 'b' and exclude from the data table all groups that contain at least one X AND at least one C in any row of the group. The order in which X and C appear is not important.

In the above example, group '2014-12-31' will be eliminated because it contains c and x (rows 1,5,6,10). Same for group '2012-12-31'. However, group '2016-12-31' will remain because while it has a C, it has no X.

My approach so far has been:

```
A[ , .( a)   ,by = .(b)][ !(a %in% c('x','c') ) ]
```

But I believe that this would remove all the rows that have 'x' OR 'c'. I am interested in removing only the ones with at least one X and one C at the same time.

Thank you,

Comment: Could you show desired result for this example? Your clause "and the other in which x and c appear is not important." is not clear to me without it.

Comment: The example data set is not unique as you forgot to call `set.seed()`.

Comment: Thank you. I meant to say "the order in which x and c appear is not important"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

logic : no need to `group_by`, just extract the `unique` `b's` that contains either `x` or `y` and then remove those entries.

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(100)
A <- data.table( a = sample(c('x','c','y',''),10, replace = T), 
                 b = sample(as.Date(c('2008-12-31','2012-12-31','2013-12-31','2014-12-31','2016-12-31')),10, replace = T) , 
                 c = runif(10)  )

split(A, A$b)
#$`2012-12-31`
#   a          b         c
#1: y 2012-12-31 0.5383487
#2: x 2012-12-31 0.7489722
#3:   2012-12-31 0.7703016
#4: c 2012-12-31 0.8819536
#5: y 2012-12-31 0.5490967

#$`2014-12-31`
#  a          b         c
#1: c 2014-12-31 0.5358112
#2: c 2014-12-31 0.4201015
#3: c 2014-12-31 0.1714202
#4: x 2014-12-31 0.2777238

#$`2016-12-31`
#  a          b         c
#1: c 2016-12-31 0.7108038

A[!b %in% intersect(b[a == "x"], b[a == "c"])]
#  a          b         c
#1: c 2016-12-31 0.7108038
```

using `group_by`

```
func <- function(dt){
  if (sum(c("x","c") %in% dt$a) != 2)
    return(dt)
}

A[ , func(.SD), by = "b"]
```

Comment: @joel.wilson small correction that he wanted to exclude groups with `x` and `c`

Comment: Hope the question is slightly clearer now. Your code excludes the last group when it shouldn't. that group has a C but no X. I want to exclude all groups that have at least one C and one X

Comment: ahhh!! @dleal then `intersect()` is the way to go as @sirallen has done.  Im completing my answer here, go with his

Comment: What would be a way to do this using group by? my actual data has more that one 'b' column and ideally I would do it by groups

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
setkey(A, a)

A[!b %in% intersect(A['x', b], A['c', b])]
```

Answer (score 0):

Changed the answer to show a `dplyr` variant

```
A %>%
  group_by(b) %>%
  distinct(a) %>%
  filter(a %in% c("x","c")) %>%
  filter(row_number()>1) %>%
  anti_join(A, ., by="b")
```

To group by multiple `b` columns e.g. `b1` and `b2`

```
A %>%
  group_by(b1,b2) %>%
  distinct(a) %>%
  filter(a %in% c("x","c")) %>%
  filter(row_number()>1) %>%
  anti_join(A, ., by=c("b1","b2"))
```

Comment: Thank you, this would remove all the observations with C or X, not C and X

Comment: @dleal changed answer to `dplyr` option as correct `data.table` option was already given